# How to add a Dynamic value as a collection in DHF5 flows source query

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

I have a requirement to add current date as a collection in DHF5 flows source query. How to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sourceQueryIsScript` as described at https://docs.marklogic.com/datahub/5.7/flows/about-flows.html . That script can then reference and variable in the `options` for a step, which includes options provided at runtime when you run the flow.